# How can I replace blocked ads with pictures (With a chrome extension)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, adblock

I want to replace all ads on any website viewed on chrome with a few pictures.  Although I don't have much experience with chrome extensions, my general coding knowledge was enough to successfully reverse engineer a couple extensions (such as catblock) to do what I wanted.

The problem I'm experiencing now is that in the location I want to run it, there is a filter on the network that blocks most ad servers, which are what the extension looks for to replace.

I have considered trying a proxy to allow the ads through, but in addition to possibly angering the network admins, it would also require me to maintain a server to keep the extension working.

The question is, how can I inform the extension where those ads would have been?  Right now it looks for iframes with common ad server's urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A firewall that blocks ads on network level would result in requests for them failing.

You can detect such instances using [`webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) (which is, incidentally, the best tool for writing ad-blockers), probably with `onErrorOccurred` event.

You can take a look at the source code for [Adblock Plus](https://github.com/adblockplus/adblockpluschrome) for some samples; in fact, quite possibly you can adapt it for your needs.

Note though - if the request fails, you may not know the intended dimensions of the ad, and as such your replacement can break the layout of the page.